# toggleClass: Remove the Current Class and Add a New Class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a green box and replace by a red box by using toggleClass.  Visually, the color changes but I need to remove a current class COMPLETELY in a div and add a new class by using toggleClass.

Problem: The current class is still there while it adds a new class in the inspector.

Please help

[jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/t6q8xzk9/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="green">

</div>

 <button id="click" value="Click">
 Click Me
 </button>
```

JS

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $('.green').toggleClass('red');
  //$('.green').toggleClass('red green');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you are using `toggleClass` method. This method adds or remove s one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

However, the way your are using it is wrong and here I will explain why. In your code you've used `$('.green').toggleClass('red green');` this is going to work only once because when the `div`'s class will change from `.green` to `.red`, there wont be `div.green` elements anymore and your script will not be applied again.

The solution is simple, just define an ID to the the element or apply an auxiliary class.

### Adding an ID

Just define an ID for the `div`, for example `element-id`. This solution will toggle the `.green` and `.red` classes only for this element, like this:

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  $('#element-id').toggleClass('red green');
})
```

```css
#element-id {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

#click {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element-id" class="green"></div>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

### With an auxiliary class

Just define an auxiliary class for the `div` like `aux-class` for this example. The advantage is that this can be applied to multiple elements like this:

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  $('.aux-class').toggleClass('red green');
})
```

```css
.aux-class {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

#click {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aux-class green">DIV 1</div>
<div class="aux-class green">DIV 2</div>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Hi Teocci, thank you very much for your help and very clear explanation.  That auxiliary class gets it works!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a different class or an id and use it to toggle between red and green classes

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  $('.toggle').toggleClass('red green');
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}

.green {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle green">
qwewqewq
</div>

<button id="click" value="Click">
 Click Me
 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are willing to use vanilla js, here's a vanilla js to achieve the toggle you are trying:

```
    <script>
    document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function(){
        let a = document.querySelectorAll('.colors')
        a.forEach((b)=>{
         if(b.classList.contains('green')){
           b.classList.remove('green')
           b.classList.add('red')
         }else if(b.classList.contains('red')){
           b.class.remove('red')
           b.class.add('green')
         }
      })
    })
    </script>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let a = document.querySelectorAll('.colors')
    a.forEach((b)=>{
     if(b.classList.contains('green')){
       b.classList.remove('green')
       b.classList.add('red')
     }else if(b.classList.contains('red')){
       b.classList.remove('red')
       b.classList.add('green')
     }
  })
})
```

```css
.colors{
   height:50px;
   width: 50px;
}
.green{
   background: green;
}
.red{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors green"></div>
<button id="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It Will replace remove the current class COMPLETELY.

```js
var data = $('#target').attr('class');

$('#target').click(function(){
    ($(this).attr('class') == data) ? $(this).attr('class','green') : $(this).attr('class',data);
});
```

```css
.blue{
   background: #17a2b8!important;
}
.green {
    background: #28a745!important;
}
h1{
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="target" class="blue">Hello World</h1>
```